# Java find min val of array in parallel

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency

In revising for an upcoming exam here is my solution to finding the min value of an array using 2 threads.

I had to create a wrapper for int to pass the minimum value around by reference.

What do you guys think?

```
public class FindMin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] data = {99,9,14,5,7,33,6,8,21,29,33,44,55,66,77,88,2, 3, 1};
        IntObj min = new IntObj(data[0]);

        Proc p1 = new Proc(0, (data.length/2)-1, data, min);
        Proc p2 = new Proc(data.length/2, data.length, data, min);

        p1.start();
        p2.start();

        try {
            p1.join();
            p2.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Min value: "+min.value);
    }

}

class Proc extends Thread {
    int ub, lb;
    int[] data;
    IntObj min;

    public Proc(int lb, int ub, int[] data, IntObj _min) {
        this.ub = ub;
        this.lb = lb;
        this.data = data;
        min = _min;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = lb; i < ub; i++) {
            compareSet(data[i]);
        }
    }
    public void compareSet(int val) {
        synchronized(min) {
            if(val < min.value) {
                min.value = val;
            }
        }
    }
}
class IntObj {
    int value;
    public IntObj(int _value) {
        value = _value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why creating an IntObj class. If each thread finds the minimum in its array you can just compare those both values after both threads finish, and return the minimum of those two values

Comment: Just some hints on clean code: private members, empty exception blocks, public methods (compareSet), consistent wording (this.ub=ub vs min=_min)

Comment: @robin Yes, I had thought of that bought I thought using a shared Integer would make the solution more scalable?

Comment: @home Thanks home, I just threw this code together I am aware of your hints, just lazy. I guess I should always try and code well as it'll generate good habits, thanks. :)

Comment: Since the array is so short, the cost of creating the threads will be your main delay.  To speed up the program you can change `p2.start()` to `p2.run()` and remove `p2.join()`, or just use one thread. ;)

Comment: You can use `int[1]` or `AtomicInteger` instead of creating an IntObj class. You don't need to search position `0` as you use this as your initial minimum.

Comment: It will also be much faster to get the minimum for each thread on it own and use compareAndSet once for the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to synchronise for each comparison, any potential gain from using two threads is more than compensated for by the synchronisation overhead. Let each thread find the minimum in its half and write the result to their own output variable. Then compare the two results in the main thread.

And your code will give the wrong result if the minimum is located at `data[data.length/2-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the abstractness of your course.

Normally one would make `min` concurrent safe: an atomic reference maybe against the assignment. Better have two results.

And certainly `volatile` if a variable is shared. In both threads the variable may be a local Copy, which might be stale.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel pointed out, leverage the parallelism by breaking down this huge tasks into smaller ones. Below is one implementation using ForkJoinPool. Courtesy: [Martin Mois](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/allalaadimised/lugemist/Java-Concurrency-Essentials.pdf)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FindMin extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int[] numbers;
    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    public FindMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {
        int sliceLength = (endIndex - startIndex) + 1;
        if (sliceLength > 2) {
            FindMin lowerFindMin = new FindMin(numbers, startIndex, startIndex+ (sliceLength / 2) - 1);
            lowerFindMin.fork();
            FindMin upperFindMin = new FindMin(numbers, startIndex + (sliceLength / 2), endIndex);
            upperFindMin.fork();
            return Math.min(lowerFindMin.join(), upperFindMin.join());
        } else {
            return Math.min(numbers[startIndex], numbers[endIndex]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[100];
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }

        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime(). availableProcessors());
        Integer min = pool.invoke(new FindMin(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1));
        System.out.println(min);
    }
}
```